# Return object in collection that has the highest (but not higher) or equal attribute value compared to given value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a collection of five objects.

The have a number attribute `day` with a unique value ranging 0-6.

If compared to a value, let's say 5 or 0, how could I find the object with equal attribute value OR the highest value in collection but not exceeding the given?

```
collection.map(&:day)
=> [0, 2, 3, 4, 6]
```

The desired return when comparing `collection` with value 5 should return the object with `day` value 4.

The desired return when comparing `collection` with value 0 should return the object with `day` value 0.

Comment: is the array always sorted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's see how the methods compare in performance. I only compare methods that do not require the array to be pre-sorted. I will edit to add other methods that are suggested.

**Methods compared**

```
module Methods
  def awendt(collection, value)
    collection_sorted_desc = collection.sort_by{|num| -num}
    collection_sorted_desc.detect{|num| num <= value }
  end

  def awendt_rev(collection, value)
    collection_sorted_desc = collection.sort.reverse
    collection_sorted_desc.detect{|num| num <= value }
  end

  def cary1(a,v)
    a.select { |e| e <= v }.max
  end

  def cary2(a,v)
    enum = a.each
    mx = - Float::INFINITY
    loop do
     x = enum.next
     mx = x if x <= v && x > mx
    end
    mx
  end

  def cary3(a,v)
    a.sort.take_while { |e| e <= v }.last
  end
end

include Methods
methods = Methods.instance_methods
  #=> [:awendt, :cary1, :cary2, :cary3]
```

**Test data**

```
def test_data(n,m)
  [[*(0..n)].shuffle, m.times.with_object([]) { |_,a| a << rand(n) }]
end

arr, cutoffs = test_data(8,3)
  #=> [[1, 5, 2, 0, 3, 8, 4, 6, 7], [5, 1, 7]]
```

**Confirm methods return the same values**

```
arr, cutoffs = test_data(1000,100)
results = cutoffs.each_with_object([]) { |c,a|
  a << send(methods.first, arr, c) }
puts methods[1..-1].all? { |m|
  cutoffs.zip(results).all? { |c,r| r == send(m, arr, c) } }
  #=> true
```

**Benchmark**

```
require 'benchmark'

arr, cutoffs = test_data(200_000, 20)

Benchmark.bm(methods.map { |m| m.to_s.size }.max) do |bm|
  methods.each do |m|
    bm.report m.to_s do
      cutoffs.each { |c| send(m, arr, c) }
    end
  end
end

                 user     system      total        real
awendt       5.140000   0.040000   5.180000 (  5.188094)
awendt_rev   1.030000   0.010000   1.040000 (  1.050535)
cary1        0.490000   0.010000   0.500000 (  0.489371)
cary2        6.740000   0.010000   6.750000 (  6.782410)
cary3        0.910000   0.010000   0.920000 (  0.919538)
```

Edit: I added a method `:awendt_rev` that replaces `collection.sort_by{|num| -num}` in `:awendt` with `collection.sort.reverse`.

Comment: `cary1` is definitely my favorite. Short, readable, and fast. Good job, this was fun!

Answer (score 2):

Here are three ways you could do it.  The benchmark I added below shows that #1 and #3 are more efficient than #2.

**#1**

```
a = [0,2,3,4,6]

def not_exceed(a,v)
  a.select { |e| e <= v }.max
end

not_exceed(a,5) #=> 4
not_exceed(a,0) #=> 0
```

**#2**

```
def not_exceed(a,v)
  enum = a.each
  mx = - Float::INFINITY
  loop do
   x = enum.next
   mx = x if x <= v && x > mx
  end
  mx
end

not_exceed(a,5) #=> 4
not_exceed(a,0) #=> 0
```

**#3**

```
def not_exceed(a,v)
  a.sort.take_while { |e| e <= v }.last
end

not_exceed(a,5) #=> 4
not_exceed(a,0) #=> 0
```

Comment: Note: This assumes the input is sorted.

Comment: @awendt's point referred to my methods #2 and #3. I changed #2 so it does not rely on the array being sorted and inserted `.sort` in #3. I don't think sorting is a good idea, however, as it's unnecessarily time-consuming for what is required. Here sorting is akin to `a.sort.last` to find the largest element of an array, rather than `a.max`, which is much more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

If the input is not sorted, you could use this:

```
def highest_or_equal(value, collection)
  collection_sorted_desc = collection.sort_by{|num| -num}
  collection_sorted_desc.detect{|num| num <= value }
end
```

And here's the test for it:

```
require 'minitest'
require 'minitest/autorun'

class Test < Minitest::Test
  def test_returns_lower
    assert_equal highest_or_equal(5, [0, 2, 3, 4, 6]), 4
  end

  def test_returns_exact_match
    assert_equal highest_or_equal(0, [0, 2, 3, 4, 6]), 0
  end
end
```

Comment: Sorting largest to smallest makes sense. Incidentally, @theTinMan has reported that `a.sort.reverse` is faster than `a.sort_by { |e| -e }` and `a.sort { |e,f| f<=>e }`. +1.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yeah, I've seen that answer on SO but I opted for readability. BTW, `.sort.reverse` was slowest in that benchmark.

Comment: Have a look at the benchmark I added to compare `sort_by {|n| -n }` with `sort.reverse`.  Interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there's only sorted numbers like you mentioned in your comment, and that all numbers are integers, you can easily use the detect function without any other needs

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6].detect {|x| x >= minimum}
```

This will return the first number that is either equal or greater than the minimum number.

**EDIT**: ok i just noticed you need the opposite, in this case you'll need to reverse the array

```
[1,2,3,4,5].reverse.detect{ |x| x <= maximum }
```